# Deploy flask app on azure web app (Windows)

Tags: azure, flask, azure-web-app-service, azure-webapps

Trying to deploy simple flask app on azure app service with windows os. I tried deploy python app on azure web services on Linux it worked. Wanted to do the same with azure web services on windows. I already have tried many resources and document but couldn't come with solution. Also do i need to upload env folder for flask application to work.

Answer (score 1):

Linux is currently the recommended option for running Python apps in App Service. As mentioned in this document - '[Python on the Windows flavor of App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/python/managing-python-on-azure-app-service?view=vs-2019)'. 
The Python extensions for App Service on Windows are deprecated in favor of a direct deployment to App Service on Linux. Virtual environments -Not supported. Instead, use bundling and set the PYTHONPATH environment variable to point to the location of the packages.